# Return pointer to any field in class/structure in C/C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, types

I have struct which contains a lot of fields with different types:

```
struct team_stats{
    char team_name[ TEAM_NAME_LEN ]; // Name of NFL team
    int games; // Number of games played in the season
    float pts_per_game; // Points per game
    ...
}
```

I create method that returns pointer to any field in my structure
It looks like:

```
template <class T>
T* getField (int fieldNum, team_stats &team) {
    if(fieldNum==0) return &team.team_name;
    if(fieldNum==1) return &team.games;
    if(fieldNum==2) return &team.pts_per_game;
    ...
}
```

For example I want to read some field :

```
template <class T>
void readTeam(team_stats &team) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_FIELDS; i++) 
        cin >> *getField<T>(i,team);
```

**Problem occurred:**

As I have a template I need to pass some type when I invoke method - getField(i, team). But I have different types of my fields and compilator will say the message something like *" can not convert **type of field games** to **some type**"*

**UPD:**
But for outer function I need to specify the type T, how to make it dynamic?

**UPD_2:**
I found the great solution! I answered my question below!

Comment: You need `cin >> getField<T>(i,team);`

Comment: It helps but it caused the same error in the outer function(`for (int j = 0; j < NO_TEAMS; j++) readTeam(arrayOfStats[i].teams[j])`). Does it possible to read fields of this struct using this approach? The problem is that I need dynamicaly indentify the type of field.

Comment: You must call it providing a type for the template parameter. Something like `readTeam<int>(team);`. Generally what you are trying to do there won't work.

Comment: Yes! I understand why this is impossible) To dereference pointer we should know exactly what is the type of this pointer. Thanks

Comment: There is one more error! When I pass the type <int> it causes the error that some field  can not be converted ( but this field never will be reachable ).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Pardon me but why is the OP's dereferencing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you implement an `operator>>(std::istream&, team_stats&)` and just read the whole struct in one go? Instead of requiring calling code to make decisions/branches about member types?

Comment: reading was an example of where I need this stuff

Comment: @PreferenceBean For example this code 

`template <class T>T* getField(int fieldNum, myClass &a)`

`{`


`if (fieldNum == 0) return &a.field1; `
`if (fieldNum ==1) return &a.field2; `


}` 

will note compile if field1 and field2 have different types.. Commpiler could say that type of field1 can not convert to type T.

Comment: @d40a: What does that have to do with what I asked? I'm suggesting writing your code so that you don't need `getField` at all. I honestly don't see what it gives you here, other than problems.

Comment: @PreferenceBean Suppose my task is to write sort algorithm which can sort my class by any field which user can specify. I will be glad to hear a better solution from you.

Comment: why don't use `switch` for `fieldNum`?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Honestly,  I have never used switch ;)

Comment: C and C++ are separate languages. Please do not tag your question with both tags unless you have a good reason to.

Comment: @d40a: I still don't see why you need `getField` and a numeric ID for that. We have `std::bind` (and even pointers-to-member if you're desperate). Or, since this is 2016, just lambda it: `std::sort(std::begin(items), std::end(items), [](const team_stats& lhs, const team_stats& rhs) { return lhs.pts_per_game < rhs.pts_per_game; });`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The solution of this problem suitable as for c++ as for c, except cin. What is wrong?

Comment: @d40a: You don't know what the solution is, which is presumably why you posted the question. Tag with only the language you're actually using. Otherwise we might give a solution in a language that you're _not_ using, and that wastes everybody's time. In this case, since C doesn't have references, this _must_ be a C++ question. You _must_ be writing a C++ program, and you _must_ be using a C++ compiler. Please don't contaminate the [tag:c] tag with C++ questions. Thanks!

Comment: @PreferenceBean thank you for providing modern alternatives!)

Answer (score 0):

So I wish answer this question by myself:

> For each type lets create and *overloaded* **getField** method where
>   first parameter is ***field number***, second - ***considered class***
>   and third is  ***result pointer to considered field*** passed by reference,
>   looks like:
>
> ```
> void getField(int fieldNum, team_stats &team, int *& res) {
>     if(fieldNum==1) res = &team.games;
>     if(fieldNum==3) res = &team.total_points;
>     if(fieldNum==4) res = &team.scrimmage_plays;
>     ....
> }
> void getField(int fieldNum, team_stats &team, float *& res) {
>     if(fieldNum==2) res = &team.pts_per_game;
>     if(fieldNum==5) res = &team.yds_per_game;
>     ....
> }
>
> void getField(int fieldNum, team_stats &team, char *& res) {
>     if (fieldNum == 0) res = team.team_name;
>     ....
> }
> ```
>
> So reading now looks like:
>
> ```
> void readTeam(team_stats &team) {
>     for (int i = 0; i < NO_FIELDS; i++) {
>         if (isCharField(i)) {
>             char * field;
>             getField(i, team, field);
>             readStringField(field);
>         }
>         if (isFloatField(i)) {
>             float * field;
>             getField(i, team, field);
>             cin >> *field;
>         }
>         if (isIntField(i)) {
>             int * field;
>             getField(i, team, field);
>             cin >> *field;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Additionally, I would say that you should break all of the bodies of the if statements into their own methods.

Comment: What do you mean? I do not understand =(

Comment: You do things like: `isXXXField(i) { ... }` and then do a bunch of operations. If those operations were contained in another method, it would look like `isXXXField(i) { doXXXStuff(i,team,field); }` and becomes more readable. Next, it would help you discover how *you actually could do this with a templated function*.

Comment: I am working on an answer to show you what I mean by that.

Comment: Yes, it definitely good advice. Thanks. And, do you think I should pass functions as a parameter to doStuff() ?, because for some fields I need a specific reading.

Comment: You definitely can pass functions as a parameter (and I have done that many times where I work when having to extend existing code bases), but it depends on the use cases. Based on what I can see from this, it could be a good solution. But I can't see the whole situation, so I can't tell for sure.